# Assert one exception OR the other

Tags: c#, nunit

Let's say I've got test methods A, B, C.
When I launch them all, test method B throws SQLiteException and everything is green and ok.

```
Assert.Throws<SQLiteException>(() => sql.Select(selectFrom + "table_name"));
```

But, when I'm launching ONLY test method B it throws ArgumentException BEFORE SQLiteException and test fails.

The question is: how to assert that one OR the other exception is thrown?

I'm talking about something like this

```
Assert.Throws<SQLiteException>(() => sql.Select(selectFrom + "table_name")).OR.Throws<ArgumentException>()
```

Comment: `try { ... Assert.Fail("Should have thrown"); } catch(ConcreteEx1) { ... } catch(ConcreteEx2) { ... } or simply to swallow the expected exceptions

Comment: Sounds like you're seeing race conditions between your unit tests, always best to write tests so they run in isolation.  Are you able to post the actual code?

Comment: It seems strange to me to have an indeterminate test, your code should be structured in a way which avoids this.

Comment: Unfortunatelly can't post the actual code. The answer below is a good workaround, but maybe I'll work on a better tests' isolation first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    somethingThatShouldThrowAnAcception();
    Assert.Fail(); // If it gets to this line, no exception was thrown
} catch (GoodException) { }
```

You should be able to adapt this approach to whatever you like, including specific exceptions you want to catch. If you only expect certain types, finish the catch blocks off with:

```
} catch (GoodException) {
} catch (Exception) {
    // don't want this exception
    Assert.Fail();
}
```

Remember that you can't do this

```
try {
    somethingThatShouldThrowAnAcception();
    Assert.Fail();
} catch (Exception) { }
```

because Assert.Fail() works by throwing an AssertionException.

You can also do this

```
try {
    somethingThatShouldThrowAnAcception();
    Assert.Fail("no exception thrown");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Assert.IsTrue(ex is SpecificExceptionType);
}
```

Comment: This solves problem you shouldn't really have. Something is wrong with your tests. All tests should pass always. It should not matter if you ran A and C before B.